# ionic-appauth is not opening sign-in screen in android

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic react project with ionic-appauth package in an ionic react package. I am able to complete the sign in process in the web. But in Android devices, it is not redirecting to the sign in screen. Nothing happens when I call `Auth.Instance.signIn()`

Using latest ionic and capacitor version

`"capacitor/cli": "5.5.1" "ionic-appauth": "^2.0.0" "@ionic/react": "^7.0.0"`

Is this some issue with configuring AndroidManifest.xml? Here is my file

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:name="com.mydomain.dev.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="com.mydomain.dev" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>

<!-- Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

`